# What is meaning of browser active history in context of popState definition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js, html5-history

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate :

> A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active
>   history entry changes. If the history entry being activated was
>   created by a call to history.pushState() or was affected by a call to
>   history.replaceState(), the popstate event's state property contains a
>   copy of the history entry's state object.

What does active history mean here?

I have a url like:
domain/?pn=1

When i click on next page button, the url becomes:
domain/?pn=2
(History changes but popState not called)

When I click on some other button, the url becomes:
domain/?pn=2#speacial
(History changes with hash and popState is called)

Can anyone explain this difference?

Answer (score 1):

> What does active history mean here?

Not a lot. *active* is a modifier to *history entry* not to *history*.

You have a history. There are URLs in it. They are the URLs that you have visited. The active one is the one you are currently looking at.

> Can anyone explain this difference?

The actual text for the URL you reference is:

> A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active history entry changes between two history entries **for the same document**.

`/?pn=1` and `/?pn=2` are different documents (assuming you aren't using `pushState`).

Changing the fragment id just points to different places within the same document `#speacial`.